# Programatically set HttpContext.Handler in classic ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net

In my CMS application, I'm trying to intercept all ASP.NET requests, inspect them and then assign custom HttpHandler if necessary or leave default handling when appropriate.
I tried setting HttpContext.Current.Handler in Application_BeginRequest but it doesn't seem to work.
There is MapRequestHandler event in HttpApplication but it is not available in the Global application class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use an HttpModule for this instead of the Global.asax.

Comment: Ok. Should I do all processing inside BeginRequest event? Somehow this doesn't feel right for me.

Comment: PostMapRequestHandler event in HttpModule is something I was looking for.